# Plural Program in C, When i run program the plural words have a bunch of random stuff after it

Tags: c

So the problem is that whenever I enter a word, the plural version of the word has a bunch of random junk that follows it. Here is an
[example of the problem](https://gyazo.com/b3810870567fc85ed9751d28299649a3)
.  This is majority of the code(if you need more of it I will put more), also if you see any other problems could you please let me know? 
Thank you so much.

```
char * getWord()
{
    //make char array of size 20 using malloc
    char *word;
    word = malloc(20);
    //give the msg to user
    printf("Enter a word ");
    //take input from user
    scanf("%s", word);
    printf("\n");
    //return word
    return word;
}
//change word to uppercase
void toUpperCase(char *word)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (word[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (word[i] >= 65 && word[i] <= 90)
        {
            //it is upper case latter so do nothing
        }
        else if (word[i] >= 97 && word[i] <= 122)
        {
            word[i] = word[i] - 32;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
//function which will determine which rule applies to given word
int findRule(char *word)
{
    int n;//length of word
    n = strlen(word);

    //last char is Y then rule 1
    if (word[n - 1] == 'Y')
        return 1;
    //end is S,CH,SH then rule 2
    else if ((word[n - 1] == 'S') || (n >= 2 && (word[n - 1] == 'H' && (word[n - 2] == 'C' || word[n - 2] == 'S'))))
    {
        return 2;
    }
    //else rule 3
    else return 3;
}
//rule one
char *ruleOne(char *word)
{
    int n;//length of word
    n = strlen(word);
    //make char array of size 20 using malloc
    char *ans;
    ans = malloc(n + 2);
    //copy all char except last
    for (int i = 0; i<n - 1; i++)
    {
        ans[i] = word[i];
    }
    //add ies in place of y
    ans[n - 1] = 'I';
    ans[n] = 'E';
    ans[n + 1] = 'S';
    return ans;
}

//rule 2
char *ruleTwo(char *word)
{

    int n;//length of word
    n = strlen(word);
    //make char array of size 20 using malloc
    char *ans;
    ans = malloc(n + 2);
    //copy all char
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        ans[i] = word[i];
    }
    //add two char E and S
    ans[n] = 'E';
    ans[n + 1] = 'S';
    return ans;
}
//rule 3
char *ruleThree(char *word)
{
    int n;//length of word
    n = strlen(word);
    //make char array of size 20 using malloc
    char *ans;
    ans = malloc(n + 1);
    //copy all char
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        ans[i] = word[i];
    }
    //add S
    ans[n] = 'S';
    return ans;
}

int main()
{
    //geets the user
    greets();
    //open file to write

    fptr = fopen("pluralWords.txt", "w");
    //if file not open
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error to open file!\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        //file opened
        printf("%s\n", "The output file pluralWords.txt is open\n");
        printf("%s\n", "---------------------------------------\n");
        while (1)
        {

            //ask the msg that user want enter a number or not y/Y(YES), n/N (NO)
            printf("%s", "Would you like to enter a word Y (YES) or N (NO)?");
            //it is for check yes or no
            char c[2];
            scanf("%s", c);

            if (c[0] == 'n' || c[0] == 'N')
            {
                printf("Thank you for trying out the Pluralizer!");
                printf("\nClosing the file pointer");
                fclose(fptr);
                break;
            }
            else if (c[0] == 'y' || c[0] == 'Y') {
                printf("\n");
                //make cahr array using pointer and malloc function
                char *word = malloc(20);
                //read input
                word = getWord();
                //convert to upper case
                toUpperCase(word);
                printf("%s\n", word);

                //find rule
                int rule = findRule(word);

                printf("Rule is %d\n", rule);

                char *ans = malloc(22);
                //call coresponding function with rule
                if (rule == 1)
                {

                    //call ruleOne
                    ans = ruleOne(word);

                }
                else if (rule == 2)
                {

                    //call ruleTwo
                    ans = ruleTwo(word);
                }
                else
                {

                    //call ruleThree
                    ans = ruleThree(word);

                }
                //output to screen
                printf("Word is %s and plural is %s\n\n", word, ans);
                //msg to user
                printf("Adding the words to the file\n");
                //wrtie to file
                fprintf(fptr, "%s   %s\n", word, ans);
                printf("\n\n");
```

Comment: I guess no null terminator present. Google that, and read what a c string really is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C-strings require a null character at the end, i.e: `['s', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g', '\0']` with '\0' being the null character.

This null character is how operations know the length of the string. String functions such as `strlen`, `strcpy`, etc, look for this null character and will keep looking through memory until they find it. In the case of printing it out, this will mean the program will print out 'garbage' memory until it finds a location that is set to \0.

In your rule... functions you are overwriting this null character and not replacing it:

```
ans[n] = 'E';     //this was NULL (/0)
ans[n + 1] = 'S';
return ans;       //ans is now missing a NULL terminator
```

As an aside, you are also malloc'ing memory but never freeing it which would result in memory leaks. In C it is generally cleaner to pass a buffer to a function rather than have it malloc memory and return it (e.g. `char* ruleOne(char* word)` would be better as `void ruleOne(char* in_word, char* out_word, int out_len)`) You could then simply create a buffer in main() as `char wordbuf[128]` and not have to worry about managing the memory yourself.